# is setw() and "\t" the same thing?

Tags: c++

Is setw() and "\t" the same thing tho?
And are they similar to **"space"** too?.
Can I use setw() in the place of "\t" or would it result in a completely different output?

Comment: Not even close no

Comment: Have you read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have almost nothing in common.

---

[`std::setw(int n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) set the width of the next element that goes into the stream. So if you have things like:

```
std::cout << "Hi," << std::setw(12) << "there!";
```

This would print:

```
Hi,      there!
   ^^^^^^ <- 6 empty spaces were made here to fill the width
```

If you set the width to be longer than the actually object streamed in to it, it will automatically fill them with spaces.

On the other hand, `'\t'` is a predefined escape sequence. And it will behave similar to when you type a <kbd>tab</kbd> in many text editors. Also note that it is actually a character, you could put that in any strings:

```
std::cout << "\tHi,\tthere!";
```

This would print:

```
    Hi, there!
^^^^   ^ <-- both of them are tabs
```

Note those tabs were made different sizes, you should be able to observe similar behaviors when using tabs in text documents. It will try to fill the current 4 block text with spaces if it was not filled yet.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not same at all.

"\t" : allocates 4 spaces;

setw() : setWidth() is a function defined in iomanip header file.
It takes a integer as parameter and allocates the width of value of the integer.
Take for an example : setw(7) It will allocate 7 spaces to you

```
cout<<setw(7)<<"Hi"<<"**";
```

Output will be : Hi + 5 Spaces + **

5 Spaces because in total you requested 7 spaces and 2 are occupied by 2 character of word "Hi".

This function is highly used where you want to display something in a very proper format.

Comment: `'\t'` doesn't allocate four spaces. It outputs the single tab character. Your console or editor will decide what to do with it.

Comment: oh yeah, I get it now